# ActionScript 3 / MXML : My code doesn't do anything

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

Compiling my code into a SWF file results in a program that does nothing. I expected a solid rectangle with color #FFAA00. Why is my code not doing anything?

dummy.as:

```
//Dependencies
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

//Variables
var GlobalTimer:int = 0;
var Rect:Shape = new Shape();

//Game loader function
public function handle():void
{
    init();
}

//Init function
public function init():void
{
    addChild(Rect);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
}

//Loop function
public function loop(event:Event):void
{
    var CurTimer:int = getTimer();
    var FrameDiff:int = CurTimer-GlobalTimer;
    GlobalTimer = CurTimer;

    Rect.graphics.beginFill(0xFFAA00);
    Rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,640,480);
    Rect.graphics.endFill();
}
```

dummy.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application width="640" height="480" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="handle()">
    <mx:Script source="dummy.as"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Compiled using:

```
./mxmlc ../../feedsparky/src/dummy/dummy.mxml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **Shape** does not meet the conditions as a child. Read carefully:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#addChild()

In order to add basic Flash display classes to Flex display list you need to have **UIComponent** as their parent. You can see the chain of inheritance here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html

```
var FlashBox:UIComponent = new UIComponent;
var Rect:Shape = new Shape;

//Init function
public function init():void
{
    addChild(FlashBox);
    FlashBox.addChild(Rect);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}
```

Comment: @Yoshimaster You are not able to create an instance of a certain class and add it as intermediate container? Okaaay...

Comment: That's it? Sorry, I was a bit confused. I don't use OOP languages very often, and therefore don't really know the terminology. I didn't understand what you meant, basically.

Comment: @Yoshimaster Yes, that's all you needed to alter - just to use empty **UIComponent** as a container for classes like **Shape**, **Bitmap**, **Sprite**, **MovieClip** or **TextField**.

Comment: Did that, but now I have another problem: my program draws the rectangle at an offset of 320X and 24Y, thus covering most of the right side of the window, but not all of it.

Comment: @Yoshimaster Because default align and scale mode are set to help animated movies fit the stage if stage width and height differs from what they were published to. Use **stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;** and **stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;**

Comment: Please also practice naming vars in camelCase

Comment: @quantomworks I do with regular variables, but prefer to give UppercaseInstanceNames to display objects.

Comment: @Organis I hear ya. Reason I say that is if you start making custom classes and do that things dont look as great.